# spark-shell Unix Timestamp Convertion & Save file to different Format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I just started learning Spark and Scala. I wish to know how to use this conversion method from Unix timestamp to data in spark-shell

```
scala> val allrecords = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table")
scala> allrecords.show()
+----------+------------+
| timestamp|endtimestamp|
+----------+------------+
|1462627176|  1462635408|
|1462627742|  1462635629|
|1462628184|  1462635203|
```

It only shows top 20 rows. Why does spark-shell only show 20 rows? Is it possible to remove this limitation?

One more question, how can I save the result to my home directory and HDFS location?

Comment: Your question title is misleading, please fix it.

Comment: This one is the best choice for me
val allrecords = sqlContext.sql("SELECT *, from_unixtime(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd ') as timestamp, from_unixtime(endtimestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd') as endtimestamp  FROM table") which will convert the both fields ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the `show()` method is `show(20,truncate=True)` , where the first argument is the number of rows to display and second argument truncates the output to 20 rows.

So you can simply use `show(<number of rows you want to see>)` or `show(<any number of rows>,False)` to display all of the rows.
To save the `dataframe` you can use
`allrecords.write().format("parquet").save("HDFSPath")`  or
`allrecords.write.parquet("HDFSPath_filename.parquet")`

Comment: Thanks for give me clear picture .I tried to save the file using this 
allrecords.rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://master:8020/location ")
what I can see that all result file are split to several part ...Is there any way to combine the result to single txt file now file are like part-00000 part-00001 part-00002 so N,My input is txt file loaded from HDFS .

Comment: Obviously, they will be split because you have saved an RDD as a Text file, RDDs are meant to be spread and distributed across the cluster. To save it as a single text file, you'll have to reduce the number the partitions by using `coalesce` . But that'll shuffle the data and it's an expensive operation. You can simply use those multiple files that have just been created by giving the directory path, it'll be a better option then combing them and making it into a huge single file. 
You can mark the answer `Accepted` as it answers your question.

Comment: Is the same thing coalesce use to save the parquet file . will you show an example for this one

Comment: Yes, to get a single Parquet file, you'll have to `coalesce` your RDDs first. Here's a link in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) on how to `coalesce`.

Comment: val allrecords1 = allrecords.coalesce(1)

Comment: Do you have any comment to convert the both time fileds in one query . If you know please .....

Comment: Convert to what ? Also, as you're new to StackOverflow, I'd like to tell you that please avoid asking multiple unrelated questions in a single post , and Upvote all the answers that you find helpful, while accepting the answer that you think is most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

its not spark-shell limit you can call show with number of rows you want like below

```
allrecords.show(100)
```

and to save the result in you home directory you can simply convert dataframe into rdd and call saveAsTextFile action on it as below

```
     allrecords.rdd.saveAsTextFile("path_where_save_file")
```

you can also save file in hdfs using saveAsTextFile action

Comment: But that is converting a DataFrame to an RDD again, and it'll lose any Schema associated with it.

Comment: yeah but you just use that for saving the file later on u can use the same dataframe for other operations or u just read that file and create dataframe with schema

Comment: Yea, but that's repeating the whole thing again and again.

Comment: yeah you are right @Yankee But we can use the same dataframe for further operations we only need to read the file file as df whenever need but yeah you are right its also much dependent on use cases. :)

Comment: Thanks Sandeep for your valuable comment

Comment: @StratQuest can you please explain in you convert timestamp in what ?

Comment: @StratQuest so you use saveAsTextFile or something else if this will helpful you just accept ot upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
val allrecords = sqlContext.sql("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000,'%Y-%M-%d) as timestamp, FROM_UNIXTIME(endtimestamp/1000,'%Y-%M-%d) as endtimestamp FROM table")
```

This should work to convert Milliseconds to Date

Comment: I got the following message `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`timestamp`' given input columns: []; line 1 pos 21'

Comment: This one works form me 
`val allrecords = sqlContext.sql("SELECT from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%M-%d') as timestamp FROM table") ` thanks

Comment: yes i mentioned it as `yourTable` in your case table name is `table`

Comment: One more help I have to convert endtimestamp also from this single query what I given is `val allrecords = sqlContext.sql("SELECT from_unixtime(timestamp,endtimestamp '%Y-%M-%d') as timestamp,endtimestamp FROM table")'
`scala> val allrecords = sqlContext.sql("SELECT from_unixtime(timestamp,endtimestamp '%Y-%M-%d') as timestamp,endtimestamp FROM table")
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
Literals of type 'ENDTIMESTAMP' are currently not supported.(line 1, pos 31)== SQL ==SELECT from_unixtime(timestamp,endtimestamp '%Y-%M-%d') as timestamp,endtimestamp FROM table'

Comment: @ toofreellik this one is not selecting table , it caused because of brackets any way your answer show me a way ...